# crypt(): different behaviour on different servers despite same PHP environment

Tags: php, hash, crypt

I'm currently setting up a staging environment, on which I ran into a problem with PHP `crypt()`. We deployed the same code with the same data into the same environment (*Ubuntu 14.04, Apache 2.2.25, PHP 5.4.17, mySQL 5.6.11*, everything set up by the same setup script), but we couldn't login into our platform. The passwords were hashed using `crypt()` as follows:

```
$saltedPassword = $userSalt . $userInput . $systemSalt;
$randomSalt = someFunctionWithMtRandOutputting22Chars();
$hash = crypt($saltedPassword, '$2y$15$' . $randomSalt);
$userDao->storePassword($hash);
```

`$userSalt` is a constant date tied with the user (like his ID), `$userInput` ist the actual password sent from the frontend. An example hash would be `$2y$15$X8ozNErDV1SU1wdTdAW7JOg/eYt4C7okLB0.9pR9HkM.fqtj7/H.e` .

To login, the portal uses this code:

```
$hash = $userDao->getPassword();
$saltedPassword = $userSalt . $userInput . $systemSalt;
$authorized = (crypt($saltedPassword, $hash) === $encryptedPassword);
// if $authorized === true, login
```

This code works perfectly fine on 5 different machines (production and development). When using the same code in the stage environment, the second `crypt()` call returns a different result, in this case `$2y$15$X8ozNErDV1SU1wdTdAW7JOsxs7kdiTp3Bp0QuuOUcYs6zXkaq6dgq` . While the salt part of the password is identical (and indicating that the correct algorithm was chosen [Blowfish]), the second part differs from the stored hash.

I tested the known constants (`CRYPT_SALT_LENGTH` and `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`) on all systems, and all values were the same. I tested the code on the command line, and all systems returned the same hash, but surprisingly not the one stored in the database, but the "wrong" one. Could this be a hint for a misconfiguration?

The only known difference between the existing, working environments and the new, faulting stage environment is, that the stage environment is set up as a `chroot` environment on our test server. Could this difference be the cause for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: my assumption, that the data on the stage environment is the same, was wrong. After crawling through some test data, we found that the `$userSalt` differed structurally from the other systems, indicating an error in the database setup routine.